# Acoplar Código (xml)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Tengo el siguiente código en aplicación de consola:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("C:\\Users\\practicasti1\\Desktop\\Xml 3.3\\Personal.xml");


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "Person")) 
            {
                if (reader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Firstname: " + reader.GetAttribute("firstname") + '\n' + "Lastname: " + reader.GetAttribute("lastname"));
                }
            }
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "Dog"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Firstname: " + reader.GetAttribute("firstname") + '\n' + "Lastname: " + reader.GetAttribute("lastname"));
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Como podrán observar estoy leyendo un xml, como tal apenas estoy aprendiendo la parte de leer los nodos. y ejecuto y me da el siguiente resultado a continuación les mostrare el resultado y el xml.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien ahora lo quiero acoplar en un form. y tengo mi siguiente código:

```
 private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {

                if ((myStream = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {

                    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {


                        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "Person"))
                        {
                            if (reader.HasAttributes)
                            {
                                reader.Read();


                               txt4.Text = ("Firstname: " + reader.GetAttribute("firstname") + '\n' + "Lastname: " + reader.GetAttribute("lastname"));
                            }


                        }
                        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "Dog"))
                        {
                            if (reader.HasAttributes)
                            {
                                reader.Read();


                                txt4.Text = ("Firstname: " + reader.GetAttribute("firstname") + '\n' + "Lastname: " + reader.GetAttribute("lastname"));
                            }


                        }
                    }

                   reader.Close();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }
             }


    }
```

Pero solo me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para empezar, metiste todo dentro de un try, y no hay nada en el catch.. yo empezaria sacando eso, a ver si tira algun error...

Comment: Para empezar,el problema es que en cada iteración estas "machacando" el contenido de tu `txt4`.  En lugar de `txt4.Text =...`, lo que debes hacer es añadir al contenido que ya existe con `txt4.Text +=...`. Por otro lado, asegurate de que `txt4` tiene la propiedad `MultiLine` a `true`.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya he resuelto mi problema.